# update rows where they are repeated in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I'm working with a pretty large database of cities.
I have several rows of cities that are repeated because they are from different countries / states.

What I need to do is:
The cities that are repeated, concatenate in this way 
`(ascii_name + "_"+ country_code)` in column: `name_city`

Only the cities that are repeated.

with this filter code those that are repeated:

```
SELECT ascii_name FROM cities GROUP BY ascii_name HAVING count (ascii_name)> 1
```

For example(img) with "Rome" I get 3 rows and I want to differentiate them in that column "name_city" with "country_code"

(It's mysql)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` query that joins with a subquery that finds all the duplicated names.

```
UPDATE cities AS c1
JOIN (SELECT ascii_name
      FROM cities
      GROUP BY ascii_name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS c2
    ON c1.ascii_name = c2.ascii_name
SET c1.name_city = CONCAT(c1.ascii_name,'_',c1.country_code)
```

Comment: #1052 - La columna: 'ascii_name' en field list es ambigua

Comment: Did you copy my original code before I edited `ascii_name` to `c1.ascii_name`?

Comment: thx this code was correct, I managed to do what I wanted. =DDD

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking.

Concatenation syntax differs based on DB. || works in ANSI concatenation operator and it works in Oracle, + works in SQL server, CONCAT function works in MySQL.

```
SELECT CONCAT(ascii_name,'_',country_code) as name_city from cities 
where ascii_name in (select ascii_name FROM cities GROUP BY ascii_name HAVING count (ascii_name)> 1)
```

Comment: if it filters me well to what I want.
I want that same thing that I update the column name_city of the whole table of those that are duplicated. (It's mysql)

Comment: @manolomanolin Sorry I don't get it. The above query will give you all the cities that are repeated. Do you also want the cities that are not repeated? without the country code concatenated

Comment: I want to update the name_city column of that select

Comment: ```UPDATE cities set name_city = CONCAT(ascii_name,'_',country_code) ```will update all rows

Comment: If you want to update only the cities that are repeated ```UPDATE cities set name_city = CONCAT(ascii_name,'_',country_code) where ascii_name in (select ascii_name FROM cities GROUP BY ascii_name HAVING count (ascii_name)> 1)```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'cities' for update in FROM clause
=(

Comment: I would create a temporary table with all the cities that are repeated and use that in the filter. ```CREATE TABLE rep_cities as SELECT ascii_name FROM cities ascii_name in (select ascii_name FROM cities GROUP BY ascii_name HAVING count (ascii_name)> 1);``` then run update ```UPDATE cities set name_city = CONCAT(ascii_name,'_',country_code) where ascii_name in (select ascii_name FROM rep_cities)```

Comment: @manolomanolin See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause for how to fix that error.

Answer (score -1):

I think your subquery should run fine

```
select ascii_name+"_"+country_code as name_city
from cities
where ascii_name in
(SELECT ascii_name FROM cities GROUP BY ascii_name HAVING count (ascii_name)> 1);
```

Comment: + operator does not work in MySQL for concatenation

Comment: @Ravishankar Sivasubramaniam , I wrote pseudo code by copying what he mentioned to give him an idea how the query will look like..Didn't execute it